# how to insert comma separated document to postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

```
,0,1,2,3,4,5,6
0,1,1,1,76.0,2.99,2005-05-25 11:30:37.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
1,2,1,1,573.0,0.99,2005-05-28 10:35:23.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
2,3,1,1,1185.0,5.99,2005-06-15 00:54:12.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
3,4,1,2,1422.0,0.99,2005-06-15 18:02:53.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
4,5,1,2,1476.0,9.99,2005-06-15 21:08:46.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
5,6,1,1,1725.0,4.99,2005-06-16 15:18:57.000,2019-04-11 18:11:50
```

Hello, I want to know how to insert this comma separated doc to postgresql.
document details are shown above.

I know timestamp need to insert like this '2019-04-11 18:11:50' .  but I don't want to add '' for all of the timestamp values.

What I want to insert datatype in order, details are below.

```
integer, integer, smallint, smallint, integer, numeric, integer, 
timestamp without time zone, timestamp without time zone
```

please let me know..

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask] and let us know what you've tried already.

Comment: Actually you don't need quotes around the dates - or at least when I try it I don't.  What datatype are you using?

Comment: Hello, if I insert timestamp data without quotes, error occurred.

Comment: There's no need quotation if I insert timestamp data, right. I did wrong because of the column dismatching. sorry for taking a time of simple mistake. thanks for all !!

Answer (score 0):

[How can I import TIMESTAMP into POSTGRES without seconds? Coming from large CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58054889/how-can-i-import-timestamp-into-postgres-without-seconds-coming-from-large-csv)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=6Jf7eTkIaR4